# Is it possible to send different files based on HTTP or HTTPS requests on Amazon S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I would like to send different response from S3 based on whether it's HTTP or HTTPS.

For example, if it's HTTP request, send http_response.json. If it's HTTPS request, send https_response.json.

Is it possible with AWS S3?

Thanks.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why?

Comment: @ceejayoz, we are hosting some css files which requires to access another file for images and etc. We are hoping to use image http url if it's a pure http request. else use https: image url.

Comment: Just serve HTTPS URLs for everything. Simple solution, safer for everyone.

Comment: You should just always use HTTPS within the CSS file. Then it will work in both scenarios.

Comment: @ceejayoz, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not possible. There is a one-to-one relationship between an S3 object and an object's key - two objects cannot share a key.

> Every object in a bucket has exactly one key. Because the combination
>   of a bucket, key, and version ID uniquely identify each object, Amazon
>   S3 can be thought of as a basic data map between "bucket + key +
>   version" and the object itself. ([Source](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Introduction.html))

You could implement this behavior through a middle layer that checked the protocol and returned an object from S3 based on the protocol.